# if (cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) == today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) + 1) not getting such underline error, how to resolve this one?

Tags: android

```
 Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();

                if (cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) == today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR)) {
                    longTermTodayWeather.add(weather);
                }

                else
                    {
                    if (cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) == today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) + 1)
                    {
                        longTermTomorrowWeather.add(weather);
                    } else
                    {
                        longTermWeather.add(weather);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Issue is facing on else if statement if (cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) == today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) + 1), error is must be one of `calender.sunday` etc..

Comment: Please read [ask] and try to frame the question in a way that it is clear what your problem is and what you want to fix.

Comment: Im facing on this line "if (cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) == today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) + 1)" it gives an error like must be one of calendar.sunday, calendar.monday so on...i just wants to fix this problem. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this answer:

```
 Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();

        if (cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) == today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR)) {
            longTermTodayWeather.add(weather);
        }

        else if (cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) == (today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) + 1))
            {
                longTermTomorrowWeather.add(weather);
            }
       else
            {
                longTermWeather.add(weather);
            }
```